# action on successful email verification

Tags: node.js, express

I have an API function that verifies a user's email but I dont really know what to do next. I want to redirect the user to an HTML page that says "your email has been verified" but I don't know if I should use `res.sendFile()` or `res.redirect()`.

I tried both of them but `res.sendFile` doesn't work when I include images because if the API is `/user/verifyEmail`, any images I include in the HTML have `src=/user/myimg` for some reason and therefore they aren't sent or dislayed. I then tried `res.redirect()` with the HTML page placed in my apps static files and this works (with the images too) but it just feels wrong because anyone can open this page if they go to `myapp/verification.html` since the file is in the static folder.

What is the right thing to do here?

Comment: res.redirect() is the right way. And, no, it doesn’t feel wrong. You can simply secure your routes by adding some middlewares, that allows only your redirection or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this concern by adding middleware for securing that routes

> but it just feels wrong because anyone can open this page if they go to myapp/verification.html since the file is in the static folder.

In conclusion, `res.redirect()` is the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set unique value in your path like

> www.xyz.com/verification/unique_value
>
> unique_value define that which user verify this page (you can encode user id and set as unique_value)
>
> then you can use GET api for www.xyz.com/verification/unique_value this path
>
> You can decode in api nad check it's user or not if it's user then you can display page(res.render()) else redirect to home page (res.redirect())